# SQL Server 2012 With table as returns nothing if one table is empty

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using a `With As` statement on two tables and returning a couple columns from each. Each query, by itself, works fine. When data is in both tables that meet the `Where` clause, it works fine. However, when one table has nothing that meets the `where` clause and the other does I get an empty return. It seems like an internal where clause would not affect the other table but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

```
;WITH Issue AS
(
    SELECT  
        I.[Title] as [Issue],
        dbo.udf_StripHTML([Discussion]) as Discussion
    FROM 
        [PSMADO].[dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView] AS P
    JOIN
        [psmado].[dbo].[MSP_WssIssue_OlapView] AS I ON I.[projectUID] = P.[projectUID]
    WHERE
        I.[status] LIKE '%Active%'
        AND I.[Category] LIKE '%Factors%'
        AND p.[Workstream] LIKE 'PSO'
), Risk AS
(
    SELECT 
        I.[Title] as [Risk], 
        dbo.udf_StripHTML([MitigationPlan]) AS Mitigation
    FROM 
        [PSMADO].[dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView] AS P
    JOIN
        [psmado].[dbo].[MSP_WssRisk_OlapView] AS I ON I.[projectUID] = P.[projectUID]
    WHERE
        I.[status] LIKE '%Active%'
        AND I.[Category] LIKE '%Factors%'
        AND p.[Workstream] LIKE 'PSO'
)
SELECT *
FROM Issue, Risk
```

Comment: Thats how `INNER JOIN` works. You need `Outer Join`, add sample data and expected result. Also why are you cross joining the result at the end ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is `LEFT JOIN`and all of `risk` and `issue` conditions would be put in `join clause`.

```
SELECT 
    P.projectUID, 
    risk.[Title] as [Risk], 
    dbo.udf_StripHTML(risk.[MitigationPlan]) AS Mitigation,
    I.[Title] as [Issue],
    dbo.udf_StripHTML(I.[Discussion]) as Discussion
FROM 
    [PSMADO].[dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView]  P
LEFT JOIN [psmado].[dbo].[MSP_WssRisk_OlapView] risk 
    ON (risk.[projectUID] = P.[projectUID] AND risk.[status] LIKE '%Active%' 
         AND risk.[Category] LIKE '%Factors%')
LEFT JOIN
    [psmado].[dbo].[MSP_WssIssue_OlapView]  I 
    ON (I.[projectUID] = P.[projectUID]  AND I.[status] LIKE '%Active%' 
        AND I.[Category] LIKE '%Factors%')
WHERE
    p.[Workstream] LIKE 'PSO'
```

I notice that `p.[Workstream] LIKE 'PSO'` equals `p.[Workstream] = 'PSO'`.

Perhaps you need `p.[Workstream] LIKE '%PSO%'`